# How to Navigate to another ViewController from Collectionview cell which is inside Tableview cell using delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, appdelegate

I am trying to navigate to another ViewController from Collectionview cell which is inside Tableview cell.

I am trying to achieve using delegate method but it's not navigating to intended viewcontroller.

Here is code that i have developed so far. I am using xib setup here.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,CustomTableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var customTableViewCell = CustomTableViewCell()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        customTableViewCell.delegate = self
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 86/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
    //Delegate method
    func passTheCurrent(tableIndex: Int, collectionViewIndex: Int) {
        print("collectionViewIndex \(collectionViewIndex)")
        let selectpile = ObjectSceneViewCtrl()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectpile, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        return customCell
    }

}
```

Here is CustomTableViewCell where i am defining delegate methods. I am calling delegate function inside collectionview didSelectItemAt method. But delegate is returning nil.

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func passTheCurrent(tableIndex: Int, collectionViewIndex: Int)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   
    var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}

extension CustomTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate {}

extension CustomTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return 15
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.passTheCurrent(tableIndex: 0, collectionViewIndex: indexPath.item)
    }

}
```

When i set break point, delegate is returning nil. What is wrong with this setup. please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do the following simple steps this may helps you

1- in your **cellForRowAt** method assign delegate to your cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    customCell.delegate = self
    return customCell
    
}
```

2- in your **CustomTableViewCell** class update your **didSelectItemAt** method with following code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let del = self.delegate
    {
        del.passTheCurrent(tableIndex: 0, collectionViewIndex: indexPath.item)
    }
}
```

Basically what we are doing now **1st** we assigning delegate to cell on each index. **2nd** in table cell class first we checking is delegate confirmed then pass the data to parent controller class.

Comment: Thank you very much Muhammad Nawaz it's working now. Appreciate your help.